# Is BLIS suitable for cross-plattform development, including Apple Silicon?

Tags: optimization, apple-m1, hpc, blas

I am currently re-working a scientific C++ project that makes heavy use of matrix-vector operations like multiplying a (skew)-symmetric matrix with a vector, adding or multiplying two vectors or summing up the entries of a vector. Performance is essential and as an (annoying but important) feature I would like to ensure good performance across many platforms. I use an Apple M1 Macbook for code testing and development, but it should run on my supervisor's AMD-based Lenovo Laptop as well as our HPC cluster's Intel Xeon CPUs.

So far, OpenMP has been my easy fix to apply vectorization or parallelization wherever needed. However, I was wondering if gains could be made by using libraries that have a (supposedly) greater tuning to different architectures. While browsing the WWW, BLIS (BLAS-like Library Instantiation Software Framework) came to my attention. Among it's many great features is a promise of ease-of-use and a great number of architectures to which optimized kernels exist. BLIS documentation does not list apple's ARM processors as a supported architecture, however, a BLIS build is available via brew. Do any of you have experience in developing with BLIS on apple silicon? Was it easy to use and did you see performance gains?

Comment: I am not aware of any other BLAS library providing *portable* performance as good as BLIS (there are slightly faster BLAS but not portable and there are more portable BLAS but slower). That being said, I am not sure BLIS supports well big-little architecture like the M1 (which are a often nightmare for developers writing multi-threaded portable apps). Actually, AFAIK, nearly all mainstream BLAS poorly supports big-little architecture (in fact, like most library/apps).

Comment: I am also not sure NUMA platforms (like AMD) is well supported though the support seems not so bad in practice (despite some users complained about sub-optimal performance). Still, BLIS is the BLAS recommended by AMD itself so I expect it to be one of the best for this platform (the MKL is often slightly faster but AFAIK it is x86-64 specific).

Comment: In practice, matrix-vector operations are not very computationally intensive (compared to matrix-matrix ones) so they tends to be quite memory-bound on many PC. The M1 has a high memory throughput so IDK for it but on AMD CPUs, most BLAS taking care of the memory should be close performance-wise. In this case, it is quite easy (for a skilled developer) to write codes as fast as BLIS. For the M1, it should be significantly harder. On the M1, you can try to compare the performance of BLIS with Apple Accelerate which is supposed to be fast (since it is write by Apple itself).

Comment: @JérômeRichard thank you so much for sharing your knowledge and experience! As you may be able to tell, I am quite a newby programmer with maybe a few months' experience in anything that goes slightly lower level than your standard C++ functions. Do you happen to know any good resources for SIMD programming more tuned to the M1? There are some excellent ones on the logic behind SIMD programming itself, but none addressed the M1's architecture AFAIK.

Comment: There is not a lot of precise official publicly-available low-level resources about the M1 specifically. However, AFAIK, the M1 is a relatively-standard ARM architecture. This means the ARM documentation applies (available on the ARM website). The SIMD instruction set is Neon. The M1 has 4 (128-bit) Neon units (for FP numbers) and 6 ALU (for integers). Some low-level information are provided on [this great page](https://dougallj.github.io/applecpu/firestorm.html) (based on reverse engineering since AFAIK Apple does provide such information sadly...). This the best one I am aware of for this.